# Delete in the middle row where the id using auto generate in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2005

I have created a database in sql server 2005 and a table with auto generate id field using count all rows table.

Also I develop a project in c# desktop application.

I have a question, if i delete 1 rows table in database where the id is auto generate by coding c#, how i set the auto generate id like id has been deleted earlier?
Because in the same time when i delete the field, the count of all rows be reduced and my count is increase.

So, my auto generate id is error because the id is conflicted.

This my auto generate id

```
public string generateIdActivity()
{
    string activity = "";
    int jml = myActivity.getCountActivity() + 1;
    if (myActivity.getCountActivity() < 10)
    {
        activity = "ACT0000" + jml;
    }
    if (myActivity.getCountActivity() < 100 && myActivity.getCountActivity() > 9)
    {
        activity = "ACT000" + jml;
    }
    if (myActivity.getCountActivity() < 1000 && myActivity.getCountActivity() > 99)
    {
        activity = "ACT00" + jml;
    }
    if (myActivity.getCountActivity() < 10000 && myActivity.getCountActivity() > 999)
    {
        activity = "ACT0" + jml;
    }
    if (myActivity.getCountActivity() < 100000 && myActivity.getCountActivity() > 9999)
    {
        activity = "ACT" + jml;
    }
    return activity;
}
```

Comment: I know what am commenting is irrelevant to the question asked here.. But this piece of code could be improvised. You are calling the function myActivity.getCountActivity() so many times. This is an unwanted overhead. You could either save the value to variable and use it or you could have used the variable (jml - 1).. this would improvise the code.. its just suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

You don't.
I recommend letting SQL sever assign the id for you (using [identity property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)).

Comment: BAD idea. Never let an identity property generate business level numbering schemes. There may be other requirements - like having no holes, which identity doesn ot guarantee (but invoice numbers for example legally require). You need a custom sequence here. And sql 2005 means that one has to be programmed.

Comment: @TomTom - who said that this is generating "business level" numbering schemes? imho it's a bad idea to use a primary key in a business context like an invoice number, and relying on contiguous sequences of keys is worse.

Comment: @StephenByrne The fact that his activity Id's are not pure numbers but start with a prefix. And using business keys as primary keys is great - there is a whole school of thought that talks about natural keys in sql. Not that I like it... but then who says primary key. Unique index has the same problem. Please think your statements through.

Comment: @TomTom - fair enough but that is at an assumption on your part about the purpose of his identities. And I don't want to derail this into a natural vs surrogate key debate, suffice to say that *in my opinion and based on personal experience*, it's a bad idea. But if it works for you, great!

Answer (score 0):

> table with auto generate id field

Here you go. Identity fields do not count the rows, the have a separate counter in the metadata tables.

So, after insert 4 you get 5 - regardless whether 4 or any other row is still there or was deleted.

But: you do not have an autogenerate Id field.

You have a very bad design.

Problem is brutally said:
* Do not count, use max
* but then - how do you handle multiple inserts at the same time by multiple users / threads?

Generally what you are looking for is a sequence which should be implemented in the database and asked for the next number. Trivial in Sql server 2012 - use the (new) sequence. With 2005 you should put your own last value into some field in a separate table.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

describes various approaches for custom sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use this approach to generating a key, because as you have already seen yourself, it leads to all kinds of problems.

Consider also what might happen if two or more instances of your application try to insert records at the same time - they could both well end up getting the same count of records in the table, and both try to send the same ID.

The simplest thing to do if you want an auto-generated key, is use an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID int identity primary key,
    SomeData nvarchar(255)
)
```

Now when you want to INSERT into the table above, you only need to use
`INSERT INTO MyTable(SomeData) Values ('hello world')` and the ID column will be automatically assigned with no clashes, ever.

You can retrieve the last generated identity from a specific connection by using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` so that you can know the ID of the record you just inserted.

**Update**: A small note on the key you are using.

I would advise against a primary key that looks like 'ACT00001' or similar because although right now it makes sense (ACTivity, very clever), *you are actually painting yourself into a corner* - if the business decides in 6 month's time that "Activities" really ought to be called "Tasks" then you're stuck with a bunch of odd looking identifiers that you can't easily change.

Better to stick with a numeric identifier for now, you can always *format* it to display 'ACT00001' and so on in your presentation code.

Identity columns get a bad rap IMHO, I don't see why they shouldn't be used in your case, or you can also use a [sequence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) (*edit: I notice that you're using SQL Server 2005 so that's actually not possible*)

Comment: Interesting enough he never says primary key. I have a pattern for my databases where there is a unique id field in most tables named Code and in some that has to follow some automatic generated mechanism (invoice number for example). Id does not automatically imply primary key - a unique index triggers the same behavior.

Comment: @TomTom yep I guess I'm also guilty of assuming :)